# Changing internal browser of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, browser, eclipse-plugin, ide

I am developing an jQuery mobile application. As it consists of web pages I want some debugging feature like **FireBug** which is not provided by eclipse internal browser.

I have searched on net but not able to find anything helpful

So If someone gone through this situation Please help me.

Are there any browsers plugin available for eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Window-> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser, there is USe Internal Web Browswer. And you can check "FireFox".[image]